# How can I manage to not lose the value of my variable in a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've been trying to return a certain list of variables, 'params' in my code. If it matches certain criteria the params become something about color and name of a person etc.

However, whenever it matches the first ones ( the third IF statement where the color gets red) I tell it to return the list, but it doesn't do that. It instead executes the last few lines of the the code and the params variable seems undefined by then 
When I console.log the params its empty at the bottom of the block, but right after i assigt them it doesn't

log outcome:

```
params Object {
  "backgroundColor": "red",
  "occupant": "Mauro",
  "prep": "OCCUPIED",
  "timeFree": "until 15:0",
}
laatste Object {}
```

. So that is my first issue. Am I getting it wrong about the return statement? shouldn't that end the method and return the list? And if I'm wrong, how do I get the desired outcome? ( when matching first three criteria, return the list only )

```
timeCalc(){
  var params = {}
  var curTime = new Date();
  this.state.events.find( event => {
    var temp = new Date(event.start)
    var end = new Date(event.end)


    if(temp.getFullYear() === curTime.getFullYear() && 
    temp.getMonth() === curTime.getMonth() && 
    temp.getDay() === curTime.getDay() &&
    temp.getHours() >= curTime.getHours()

    ){
      if( temp.getHours() == curTime.getHours()){
        if( temp.getMinutes() == curTime.getMinutes()){
          params = {
            prep: 'OCCUPIED',
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            occupant: event.title,
            timeFree: "until "+end.getUTCHours()+":"+end.getMinutes()
          }
          console.log('params',params)

          return params;
        }}
         else{
            var params = {
              prep: 'FREE',
              timeFree: "until "+temp.getUTCHours()+":"+temp.getMinutes(),
              backgroundColor: '#009DDC',
              occupant: null

            }
            return params;
          }
        }
    }
    else{
      var params = {
        prep: 'TEST',
        timeFree: "nooit",
        backgroundColor: "yellow",
        occupant: "Niemand"
      }
      return params;
    }
    }
  )
  console.log("laatste",params)
  return params;

}
```

And secondly:

The params somehow make it to this part of my code, where all of the logs tell me the variables are undefined, yet the setstate below that  takes the backgroundColor variable, while the other 3 don't seem to. Why is only the background color being set and not the other 3?

```
  var params = this.timeCalc();
  console.log(params.prep);
  console.log(params.timeFree);
  console.log(params.backgroundColor);
  console.log(params.occupant);
```

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

```
  this.setState({

    prep: params.prep,
    timeFree: params.timeFree,
    backgroundColor: params.backgroundColor,
    occupant: params.occupant

  })
```

I understand this is chaotic, I tried my best in putting this up as clearly as I can and I hope you understand and might be able to help me out. Please ask me anything or give advice on how to better voice this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see this.state.events being populated anywhere - can you confirm you have data in the timeCalc() function?

Comment: @Chev I didn't upload the whole code since it thought it might be too much, but yes the state.events is populated in the constructor and it has some test events in it. The first log shows the some of the events data passed the if statements. Or is you question to me to upload the rest of the code? If so, I could

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

The way you're using `.find()` is inefficient and is causing issues. Instead of doing all of the logic in the find callback, use it to fetch the correct `event` and then transform it into params:

```
timeCalc() {
  let params = {};
  let curTime = new Date(), start, end;

  let event = this.state.events.find(e => {
    start = new Date(e.start);
    end = new Date(e.end);

    return start.getFullYear() === curTime.getFullYear() && 
    start.getMonth() === curTime.getMonth() && 
    start.getDay() === curTime.getDay() &&
    start.getHours() >= curTime.getHours();
  });

  if(start.getHours() != curTime.getHours()) {
    return {
      prep: 'FREE',
      timeFree: "until "+start.getUTCHours()+":"+start.getMinutes(),
      backgroundColor: '#009DDC',
      occupant: null
    };
  } else if(start.getHours() == curTime.getHours() && start.getMinutes() == curTime.getMinutes()) {
    return {
      prep: 'OCCUPIED',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      occupant: event.title,
      timeFree: "until "+end.getUTCHours()+":"+end.getMinutes()
    };
  }
}
```